# enable enumerable on a specific property of an object javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I'm still starting to learn javascript OOP and prototyping. and having trouble with enumerable when and how to use it and been searching on the docs still no luck. I have the following codes, where when I call:

```
users.hasOwnProperty('addUser'); // retruns true, I want it to be false.

function Chat(u) {
   this.username = u;
   this.inbox = [];
}
var users = {
    addUser: function(ins) {
        this[ins.username] = ins;
    }
};
users.addUser(new Chat('id1000'));
```

Is this possible? if it is is this a good practice?
cheers!

**what i've done so far:** using Object.defineProperty

```
Object.defineProperty(users, 'addUser', { // this says Uncaught TypeError
   set function(ins) {
       this[ins.username] = ins;
}
});
var users = {};
```

Comment: It'll work fine until you have a user named `addUser`. You shouldn't mix data and methods, if you're going to use an object as a key/value store, use it *only* for that purpose.

Comment: @meagar is it possible to call users.addUser() if I put it inside object user's prototype? like users.prototype.addUser = function()..?

Comment: You can use [*Object.defineProperty*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) to create non–enumerable properties. Also see [*MDN—Object.defineProperty*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). So yes, it's possible in ES5 compliant hosts. Whether it's a good idea depends on the rest of the design, options for achieving the same result and criteria for "good".

Comment: I'd suggest you add an object to your instance data for the `Chat` object and store the names in that object - then there is no conflict between user names and method names.  That is likely a better way to go than using Object.defineProperty to try to hide some names because even though you've hidden them from enumeration they would still be conflicts with user names.

Comment: @AnthonyLloveras it wouldn't matter if you could. Setting `this['addUser'] = ...` would shadow whatever was in the object's prototype.

Comment: @RobG thanks!, I've been trying to do that. but still no luck. please see my edited post what I've done so far. it gives me an error

Comment: @meagar hmm I think the result will be the same.